# Laravel api Authenticate - 500 error in login

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

i have laravel api in my site , it work fine in localhost but when deploy on heroku , it work good for Signup and signupActivate but for Login i get error 500

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);

    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    $credentials['active'] = 1;
    $credentials['deleted_at'] = null;

    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => __('auth.login_failed')
        ], 401);

    $user = $request->user();

    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;

    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);

    $token->save();

   // return $token;

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse($tokenResult->token->expires_at)->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
}
```

> {
>       "message": "Server Error"
>   }
>
> 500 Internal Server Error
>   A generic error message, given when no more specific message is suitable.

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: why you have 2 return ? ` return $token;` and  `return response()`

Comment: Sorry this is like a comment :)

Comment: check log storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: Did you remember to run the migrations for the passport tables on the other server?.

Comment: Yes, I did so :(

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry that I could not answer before, but I hope this can be helpful for someone with a similar problem.

When you have an error and do not find the problem, try to see the log that is in `logs/laravel.log`

I had an auth error and the only thing that I could do was get a message that contained `500 internal server error`.

When I read the log, I found an error in the database credentials, because I was editing the `.env` file on master branch with the production credentials, but when I was trying to add another feature, this data was saved in cache, when I erased the cache, the error was solved.

Remember, the `logs/laravel.log` is your best friend when you want to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **APP_URL** param in .env file, it shoud be correct.

And check app/Http/Kernel.php file

```
'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

Comment: In my case, problem was: 

`app/Http/Kernel.php:
'api' => [ 
 \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
 ...
`

When I commented this line, error 500 gone. (But, I would like to find a better solution, not just comment this line).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding try..catch.. to your code and check the exact error message your are getting.

```
try{    
    // your code here.    
}catch(Exception $e){    
     dd($e);    
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Same result
{
    "message": "Server Error"
}

Comment: I am getting a similar error. Token is successfully created but then I get a 500 response when trying to authenticate. I get a message saying "The token could not be parsed from the request" and it references line 204 in tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTAuth.php. Line 204 says it should return a 400 response, so not sure why I'm getting 500. Same exact code works on my production and dev environments just not staging env